# Sorting Students by Grades and Alphabet order c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to make program that can sort student by grades and by Alphabet order. Can someone tell me, which is the best and easyiest way to solve this  problem

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    string name;
    int grades;
    int score;
public:
    string Name() { return name;  }
    int Score() { return score; }
    char Grades() { return grades;  }

    void setName(string n) {
        name = n;
    }

    void setScore(int score) {
        score = s;
    }

    void setGrades(char g) {
        grades = g; 
    }

};Student


void sortByScor(int n, Student data[]);
void sortByAlphabet (int n, Student data[]);



void main() {

    Student s[20];
    int max = 0;
    int size = 0;
    char cek = 'y';
    while (cek == 'y') {

        system("cls");
        cout << "Enter number of student: ";
        cin >> size;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "student" << i+1 << "name: ";
            cin >> s[i].Name;
            cout << "Grades of student" << i + 1 << "score:";
            cin >> s[i].Grades;
            if (s[i].Score >= 90) s[i].Grades = 'A';
            else
                if (s[i].Score >= 80) s[i].Grades = 'B';
                else
                    if (s[i].Score >= 70) s[i].Grades = 'C';
                    else
                        if (s[i].Score >= 60) s[i].Grades = 'D';
                        else
                            s[i].Grades = 'F';
            if (max < s[i].Score) max = s[i].Score;
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0;i < size;i++) {
            cout << i + 1 << "student" << endl;
            cout << "name of student:" << s[i].Name << endl;
            cout << "score of student" << s[i].Score << endl;
            cout << "grade of student" << s[i].Grades << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "highest grade: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0;i < size;i++) {

            if (s[i].Grades == max)
                cout << s[i].Name << endl;
        }
        sortByAlphabet(size, s);
        sortByScor(size, s);
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0;i < size; i++) {

            cout << s[i].Name << endl;
        }
    }

}

void sortByAlphabet(int n, Student data[]) {


}

void sortByScore(int n, Student data[]) {

    int i, j, min;
    Student tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; j++) {
        if (data[j].Name < data[min].Name)
            min = j;
    }
    tmp = data[i];
    data[i] = data[min];
    data[min] = tmp;



    system("Pause");



}
```

Comment: Is there any reason for which you cannot use std::sort with a custom comparator? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: You are looking for a sorting algorithm to solve this. One of the simplest sorting functions that would work for this would be bubble sort.

Comment: It looks like you've skipped ahead a bit. Practice on sorting just an array of integers first.

Comment: [OT]: Your getters should be const.

Answer (score 1):

With `<algorithm>` and `std::sort`:

```
void sortByScore(int n, Student data[])
{
    std::sort(data, data + n, [](const Student& lhs, const Student& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Score() < rhs.Score();
    });
}

void sortByAlphabet (int n, Student data[])
{
    std::sort(data, data + n, [](const Student& lhs, const Student& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Name() < rhs.Name();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> the best and easyiest way to solve this problem

The best and easiest way is to define the `operator<` for your student `class`.

Example of `operator<`

```
bool operator< (const Student& left, const Student& right){ 
    if(left.Grades() == right.Grades()){
        if(left.Name() == right.Name()){
             return false;
        }
        return left.Name() < right.Name();
    }
    return left.Grades() < right.Grades();
}
```

And then use the standard `std::sort` function. When you use the `sort` function the `operator<` define for the student class is used.

```
std::sort(s, s + size);
```

EDIT: If you want two separate functions to sort by `Grade` OR `Name`. You can define two different comparison functions and pass them to `std::sort` (as explained in Jarod42 answer)

Comment: He has to sort them by score and by name, so maybe it would be better to use custom compare functors and pass them to `std::sort`.

Comment: I guess the *and* means having two different sort functions, not one based on two parameters. That's all.

Comment: The operator may be simplified (and corrected) to `return std::make_tuple(lhs.Grades(), lhs.Name()) < std::make_tuple(rhs.Grades(), rhs.Name());`

Comment: As `if(left.Name() == right.Name()){ return true; }` is incorrect.

Comment: @Jarod42 you are right, it is a `<` operator. I corrected the post

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to either write a sorting algorithm or to use conventions that are built into c++. Here is an example of the bubble sort sorting algorithm working with the students name. I recommend reading into sorting algorithms to get a better understanding of this, and other algorithms

```
void sortByAlphabet(int n, Student data[])
{
    bool swapped = true;
    while (swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            if (data[i + 1].Name() < list[i].Name())
            {
                swap(list[i + 1], list[i]);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```